# Adding custom animation to popToRootViewController

Tags: ios, animation

I am trying to create a custom animation for pop to root view controller. I would Like to create an animation where the current user slides down and reveals the new view controller beneath, along with some other things I will add. My big problem is that I can't figure out how to add a custom animation to `popToRootViewController`. I have created a custom animation to presentViewController but can't figure out how to do the same thing with `popToRootViewController`. Any help would be great, by the way I do not necessarily need help with making the controller slide down, I just need help making the controller show with any animation. Here is how I have created a custom animation for presenting a view controller:

```
FeedViewController *feed = [[FeedViewController alloc] init];
feed.transitioningDelegate = self;
feed.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
[self presentViewController:feed animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol method:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                  animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                               fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                 toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
```

At that point you should be able to plug in your transitioningDelegate (return! )

You can return `nil` if you don't want to use your custom controller. For instance you could use

```
{
   if(operation==UINavigationControllerOperationPop)
   {
      return MYTRANSITIONINGDELEGATE;
   }
}
```

Make sure you set your navigationController's delegate ;)

Comment: would I set the delegate like `self.navigationController.transitioningDelegate = self;` or like `self.navigationController.delegate`

Comment: Forget my previous question, the only thing I was wondering is how to provide different animation for different view controllers, so I would only return MYTRANSITION if pushing FeedViewController

Comment: you can check the toVC/fromVC, and chose your transitioningdelegate accordingly! Please make sure that in a 'POP' transition the fromVC is the 'newer' viewController (they are exchanged from push to pop)