# ios Disable NavigationBar back button

Tags: ios

Is it possible to disable temporarily the NavigationBar Back Button?

I manipulate the **NavigationController.ViewControllers** property and the right place to do it is in **ViewDidAppear()**. On the other hand, **ViewDidAppear()** is called quite late since the screen is animated. So a user presses the back button before **ViewDidAppear()** is called and causes havoc in the synchronization between the stack of view controller and the stack associated with the Back button. If the user waits a bit and **ViewDidAppear()** gets called, everything works OK. Hence my need to disable temporary the BackButton.

Thank you,
donescamillo@gmail.com

Comment: use this:  `[self performSelector:@selector(waitForNavigation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];`

Answer (score 0):

Using a delay as suggested in the comments would work but it's not necessarily a good thing to do. You shouldn't really create artificial delays in your code. Different devices will perform your viewDidAppear method at different speeds and you will have to set your delay to wait for the slowest device, artificially reducing the responsiveness for people on faster devices. If you could explain what you're doing fully maybe there is a more appropriate solution.

Comment: And why do you need to modify the ```viewControllers``` property on ```UINavigationController```

Comment: I have three screens: s1, s2, s3. I want to go s1->s2->s3, but s3->s1. In iOS7 I used PopToViewController, in iOS8 when PopToViewController is executed I see s1 for a split second before going to s3.

Comment: Have you tried ```popToRootViewController:```? Also if you don't want to see the s2 when popping back to s1 you could disabled animation - or write your own custom transition. Directly modifying the ```UINavigationController```s ```viewControllers``` array for this purpose (or for most purposes) isn't a good idea. You might find this question on custom transitions helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774495/adding-custom-animation-to-poptorootviewcontroller

Comment: I do not want to go straight to the Root View Controller. I tried disabling the animation but it did not work on ios8. As for modifying the stack, I did not want to do it but did not have a choice

Comment: Have you tried a custom transition. That should allow you to bypass the s2 controller.